# C++ did not open some existing file

Tags: c++

I tried to write some code in C++ that traverses all system files. The problem was that there are some files which returns an error (2) which mean no such file found. Although the path had been found, but cannot been opened or get the pointer on that file or folder!

```
dirp->search_handle = FindFirstFileA (dirp->patt, &dirp->find_data);
if (dirp->search_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
{ 
    cout << "Error(" << errno << ") opening " << dir<<" erroeno:"<<strerror(errno)<< endl<<endl;
}
```

The problem is not caused by a lack of administrator permissions because I am an admin on my computer. So what might cause this problem?

Answer (score 1):

There are other reasons you could lack permissions

- You could be trying to traverse a directory owned by another user on your domain.  Being an Administrator doesn't automatically give you access to all files on a machine.
- What you're passing could just have a trivial error.  For example, you might have passed "C:\temp", without properly escaping your backslash, and instead getting a tab character.

I would provide more information about what specifically you're passing, or perhaps read up on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: the path sent as parameter absolutely correct because it is coming from another method reading the paths from the system ., and calling automatically the code above., and for the files owned by other users ., there is no other user on my device ., it just the admin ., thank you in advance

Comment: Can you just make it just call the single path that is failing?  Can you navigate to that exact path in explorer?  Can you open the file in notepad?  Hopefully, checking one of these will provide additional information to help you track down your problem.

Comment: this is what i didnt understand it that some of them are not visible to me so i cant navigate them in explorer , and the other part they are visible i can reach them but when i double click on the "folder" a pop message talking :you dont cuurently hav permissions to access this folder , and prompt me to click on contine button to have a permanent permission to access this folder.,

Comment: so that if i clicked on it , the next time it will be opened in c without any error ! but they are too much so i cant handle this issue by hand ., this for folders ., for files : i took one of them and go to it's exact path and try to open it prevented me talking that this file being used by another process ., the importance that my system should traverse all system files and should be able to open any file ..

Comment: Try turning off User Access Controls - in win7 at least, open start menu and type UAC, and press enter, then set the option to the lowest setting.  If you're really committed to always be able to access all folders, you should probably stop using Windows

Comment: i have turned it off , still there is some files cant be opened ., i think windows as OS has some limitations which make other Oses like linux is much better than win7 ., thank you in advance too.